# Create a list of dictionaries from another list and a static value, using Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to create a list of dictionaries using only Jinja2 from another list, as input.
One key/value pair is static and always the same, the other changes value.

Input:

```yaml
targets: ["abc", "qwe", "def"]
```

I know that the server will always be `xyz`.

Final

```yaml
connections:
  - { "target": "abc", "server": "xyz" }
  - { "target": "qwe", "server": "xyz" } 
  - { "target": "def", "server": "xyz" }
```

I tried this:

```yaml
"{{ dict(targets | zip_longest([], fillvalue='xyz')) }}"
```

But, that just takes one for key and the other for value.

Comment: using only jinja2  is unclear....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close.

But you'll need a [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) rather than a `zip_longest` to have the same element repeating for all the element of your `targets` list.

You were also missing a [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) to close the gap and have the resulting list out of your dictionary.

Which gives the task:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    connections: >-
      {{
        dict(targets | product(['xyz']))
        | dict2items(key_name='target', value_name='server')
      }}
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        connections: >-
          {{
            dict(targets | product(['xyz']))
            | dict2items(key_name='target', value_name='server')
          }}
      vars:
        targets:
          - abc
          - qwe
          - def

    - debug:
        var: connections
```

This yields:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  connections:
  - server: xyz
    target: abc
  - server: xyz
    target: qwe
  - server: xyz
    target: def
```

Answer (score 1):

just use set_fact with the right loop:

```
- name: testplaybook jinja2
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    targets: ["abc", "qwe", "def"]

  tasks:
    - name: DEFINE VARIABLE SPINE
      set_fact: 
        connections: "{{ connections | d([]) + [ {'target': item, 'server': _server} ] }}"
      loop: "{{ targets }}"
      vars:
        _server: xyz

    - name: display
      debug:
        var: connections
```

result:

```
connections:
- server: xyz
  target: abc
- server: xyz
  target: qwe
- server: xyz
  target: def
```